# scraping an HTML file

Tags: html, xpath, lxml

I am trying to scrape a date from a web page which corresponds to the lastest upload date. The html file looks like below :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>
 <head>
  <title>some_text_here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<pre>
<img src=".." alt=".." ..> <a href="some_link"> 27-May-2015 02:13   25K
<img src=".." alt=".." ..> <a href="some_link"> 25-May-2015 05:13   26K
<img src=".." alt=".." ..> <a href="some_link"> 20-May-2015 00:13   20K
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the date "27-May-2015" does not have any tags attached to it. How can I use xpath in this situation:

```
page=request.get("link_to_the_page")
tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
date=tree.xpath('//tag_name/????')
```

I found that the format for identifying this is like the above but what would be the tag name here?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
date=tree.xpath('/html/body/pre/a')
```

Or more insufficient:

```
date=tree.xpath('//a')
```

It would be nice if the `<a>` would have some specific CSS class which you could select on. For example `<a href="some_link" class="date"> 27-May-2015 02:13   25K</a>`

Then you could use:

```
date=tree.xpath('/html/body/pre/a[@class="date"]')
```

Or more insufficient:

```
date=tree.xpath('//a[@class="date"]')
```

Comment: I don't know much about `tree` (is that lxml?), but `a["date"]` is nonsensical as XPath (it's not invalid, but the predicate does nothing). Do you mean `a[@class="date"]`?

Comment: You are right. I forgot the add the attribute. Thanks for the update.

Comment: Thanks **but** doing the above `date=tree.xpath('/html/body/pre/a')`returns a list like ` [<Element a at 0xa2a1c2c>, <Element a at 0xa2a1c5c>,...]` and not the date. Any other ideas ?

Comment: @lets_try: Ofcourse it does. it returns all `<a>` elements. If you want to return all text nodes you could try `/html/body/pre/a/text()`

Comment: yup got it ... It was more like `//pre/text()`

Comment: I was wondering if `/html/body/pre/a/text()` would return the text within the <a> tags right ??? or am I wrong ? . Thanks anyway :)